Mysql Query batched result grouped
I wish to achieve something like this from a MYSQL SELECT query
I wish to group the results from the select in 500 rows (per batch) and have a column called group (or anything) for the key to the group (eg bartch 0 1 2 3)
SELECT * TABEL WHERE X 

Would I do the select into a temp table with the a column-indexed then some how do a limit of 500  and move forward?
The reason behind this is  so I can call the number again to get all the same rows again.
Or would it be a better idea to just to select everything thing and let the PHP or Python do the work?
+----+------------+
| Group | Name    
+------------------
|   1   |  Ham
|   1   |  Bread
+------------------
|   2   |  Tomato
|   2   |  Eges

SELECT * FROM TABLE 


The idea is to first calculate the data belonging to the same group and then group by the group number. Since I don't know what will be done after grouping, I will use concatenating the grouped strings as an example.Using ROW_NUMBER() generates a row number, and by subtracting 1 and dividing by the number of rows per group, we calculate the group number, applying the FLOOR() function to round down in the outer layer.Because x/x = 1, if the row number starts from 1, rounding down will result in the number of groups being one less than needed (for example: 1 to (x-1) will be batch 1, and x to (2x-1) will be batch 2...).Therefore, we need to subtract "1 from the row number" to achieve the effect of grouping as 1 to x.
-- The group number corresponding to each row of data is calculated
with batchMap as (
    select
        floor((row_number() over () -1) / 500) + 1 batch,
        name
    from t
)
-- Group data with the same group number
select
    batch,
    group_concat(name,',')
from batchMap
group by batch
order by batch


him interesting, let me give this a go .. see if  it works
Thanks for the quick reply ..

The main issue here could be this:

The reason behind this is so I can call the number again to get all the same rows again.

To be sure to fetch the same rows of groups (0, 1, 2, ...) it is essencial to have the same and consistent order by to define your groups. It is not clear from the question do you have such a column(s) to do the ordering consistently.
1. table data with ID column to be used in Order By (consistently)
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl_with_id ( id int, food text );
Insert Into tbl_with_id VALUES
  ( 1, 'Ham'),
  ( 2, 'Bread'),
  ( 3, 'Onion'),
  ( 4, 'Garlic'),
  ( 5, 'Potato'),
  ( 6, 'Salad'),
  ( 7, 'Rice');
Select * From tbl_with_id;




id
food




1
Ham


2
Bread


3
Onion


4
Garlic


5
Potato


6
Salad


7
Rice



--      S Q L :    (group/batch of 3 rows)
Select    id, food, 
          FLOOR( ( Row_Number() Over(Order By id) - 1 ) / 3) as grp
From      tbl_with_id




id
food
grp




1
Ham
0


2
Bread
0


3
Onion
0


4
Garlic
1


5
Potato
1


6
Salad
1


7
Rice
2



... if you add a new row with a new id ...
Insert Into tbl_with_id VALUES ( 8, 'Beans' );

... and run the SQL again the new row (8, 'Beans') will be added at the end, but all previous group data willl remain the same ...



id
food
grp




1
Ham
0


2
Bread
0


3
Onion
0


4
Garlic
1


5
Potato
1


6
Salad
1


7
Rice
2


8
Beans
2



2. table data without a column to be used in Order By (consistently)
S a m p l e    D a t a :



food




Ham


Bread


Onion


Garlic


Potato


Salad


Rice



... if you don't order your data there could be different arbitrary ordering whenever you run the code ... so lets order it by food
--      S Q L :    (group/batch of 3 rows)
Select    food, 
          FLOOR( ( Row_Number() Over(Order By food) - 1 ) / 3) as grp
From      tbl_no_id

R e s u l t :



food
grp




Bread
0


Garlic
0


Ham
0


Onion
1


Potato
1


Rice
1


Salad
2



... now if you add a new row with a new food ...
Insert Into tbl_with_id VALUES ( 'Beans' );

... and run the SQL again the new row ('Beans') will change the group content where it was inserted and all following groups content ...



food
grp




Beans
0


Bread
0


Garlic
0


Ham
1


Onion
1


Potato
1


Rice
2


Salad
2



fiddle
UPDATE:
... the same result with MYSQL 5.7 code:
Select    id, food, 
          FLOOR( ( (@rn := @rn + 1) - 1 ) / 3) as grp
From      tbl_with_id t, ( Select @rn := 0 ) rn
Order By  id

See the fiddle here.

Yes I do have a index column if   that's your referencing

note I am using MYSQL, not SQL hence the statement is having a problem
, FLOOR ( ( Row_Number() Over(Order By  id) - 1 ) / 3) as grp

@user34416 Did you visit the fiddle link at the end of the answer - this is MYSQL ( 8 ) code and it works. If you have an older version then  you should've posted which one it is.  Or you can adjust the code from the answer to your version.

taking a look now

Do not see the link

I see, i am using 5.7.22-standard  it think that will not work, (over and row_number is for 8)
however, i will test this  locally

@user34416 Just posted an update for 5.7 at the end of the answer.

"to get same batch again"?
Maybe you are talking about pagination?
Try offset and limit,
and to keep "same batch", an order by will be good
SELECT * TABEL order by field limit 10 offset 10

